# OneSignal - security concerns

Tags: security, onesignal

I have a couple of questions about the OneSignal notification service. I have been reading the documentation and there are couple of things that bother me security-wise or I'm missing something.

As I understand the process Javascript client uses the Web Push SDK to communicate with the OneSignal API. To instantiate the communication it needs appId parameter, which is available to client.

After that the client can call getExternalId, getEmail, getTags methods to potentially gather user sensitive data. Once in possession of that data on some other device methods setExternalId and setTags can be called with gathered data to impersonate other user and receive notifications directed to them (at least those that get routed using the set parameters).

Does OneSignal presume that device (endpoint) is not compromised?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[OneSignal doesnt see `setExternalId` misuse as a security concern](https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Website-SDK/issues/520#issuecomment-494185944), as notifications shouldn't include sensitive information, as stated in their webpush SDK github.

Only recommendations they do about `external_id` are its uniqueness, and complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Clients can only call getTags, getEmail, getExternalId, and other methods if they know the subscriber's OneSignal player_id. Since the player_id is only known by the client, it is not possible to impersonate the user or to get this data.

Even so, OneSignal recommends against storing sensitive data in tags or other fields.

Comment: It's possible if you are in possession of one's device and therefore of it's player_id.